# Rspec let scoping with shared examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

I'm with a problem with let and shared examples. What's happening is that my second shared_context let is overriding the first.

Example:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "an example" do
  include_context "a"
  include_context "b"
end

shared_context 'a' do
  let(:let_example) { p 'let_example a' }

  include_context "c"
end

shared_context 'b' do
  let(:let_example) { p 'let_example b' }

  include_context "c"
end

shared_context 'c' do
  before do
    let_example
  end
end
```

It's always printing `let_example b`.

Comment: you're reassigning the variable so what else would you expect?

Comment: @Anthony I just don't want to repeat myself. I have similar tests that changes only a variable, that's why I'm using let in a higher level context. Worked for me put `include_context "a"` and `include_context "b"` each one in a context. But don't know if it's the right way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your example method re-defining has been done. When `include_context 'a'` has been executed then it defines `let_example` as a method which prints `'let_example a'`. But when you `include_context 'b'` has been executed then redefines the method `let_example` which would effectively prints `let_example 'b'`.